# OpenCV How to apply filter on image with CUDA kernel?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, memory-management, cuda

I want to apply a filter to an OpenCV ROI from Lenna 512x512 using CUDA. But I think I'm having troubles copying data properly from host to device.

I realized the Mat object isn't continuous, hence, the ROI matrix dimensions are not as expected; step[0] is much larger than cols*elemSize().

When I see [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWNPo.jpg), I see the filter is applied in almost all the image's width.
I've tried to adjust the total bytes number, but it just changes the filter's height.

I want to apply the filter at least inside the black rectangle (194x194) without using OpenCV CUDA API (GpuMat)

This is my current code:

**main function**

```
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int THREADS = 8;
    
    //Load Image
    string path = "../resources/lenna.png"; //512x512 size
    Mat img = imread(path);

    //Load haarcascade
    CascadeClassifier faceCascade;
    faceCascade.load("../resources/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");

    Mat img_gray;
    cvtColor(img, img_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    vector<Rect> faces;
    faceCascade.detectMultiScale(img_gray, faces, 1.1, 10);

    for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++){
        //The int conversion is needed for my final filter (blur).
        img.convertTo(img, CV_32SC3);

        Rect R = setROI(faces[i]); //Adjust black rectangle region.

        Point top_left = R.tl();
        Point bot_right = R.br();

        int w = bot_right.x - top_left.x;
        int h = bot_right.y - top_left.y;

        Mat faceROI = img(R);
        faceROI.convertTo(faceROI, CV_32SC3);

        //Filter apply
        myFilter(faceROI, w, h, THREADS);

        //Draws rectangles. Green one is for detected face and black one is for previous adjustment.
        rectangle(img, faces[i].tl(), faces[i].br(), Scalar(0, 255,0), 3);
        rectangle(img, top_left, bot_right, Scalar(0,0,0), 3);

        //Recover original format.
        img.convertTo(img, CV_8UC3);

        imwrite("../resources/test.jpg", img);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**myFilter**

```
void myFilter(Mat face, int w, int h, int THREADS){
    //It's confirmed that w, h = 194

    /*CUDA WORK*/
    int faceBytes = face.step[0]*face.rows;  //Should be face.elemSize()*sizeof(int)*w*h = 3*4*194*194, but it gives 3*4*512*194
    //face.isContinuous() gives 0
    //face.rows = face.cols = 194

    int *d_face;
    cudaMalloc<int>(&d_face, faceBytes);

    cudaMemcpy(d_face, face.ptr(), faceBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    dim3 threadsPerBlock(THREADS, THREADS);
    dim3 numBlocks(ceil(w / threadsPerBlock.x), ceil(h / threadsPerBlock.y));

    myFilterKernel<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_face, w, h, face.step1());

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaMemcpy(face.ptr(), d_face, faceBytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(d_face);
}
```

**myFilterKernel**

```
__global__ void myFilterKernel(int* d_face, int width, int height, int faceStep){
    int x = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;

    int face_c = faceStep /width; //Channel count, it should be 3
    
    if (y < height && x < width){
        //Thread pos
        int face_tid = y * faceStep + (face_c * x); 

        //Filter
        for (int i = 0; i < face_c; i++){
            d_face[face_tid + i] *= 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post a minimal reproducible (and executable) code sample? For example: remove the Classifier, and replace it with the output of the Classifier. Remove the loop, and execute the filter only once...

Comment: @Rotem I don't really know what does the Classifier outputs but the resource can be downloaded [from here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml). The loop just executes once since there is just one detected face (but it generalizes for variable images). I'll include the headers and namespaces.

Comment: I'm sure the problem doesn't lie on the image loading or the face detection output (even if it is the reason why the Mat object is not continuous I couldn't change that portion of the code). So the problem reduces to apply a filter in a subregion of any uncontinuous opencv::Mat image (maybe a hard-coded region) by a CUDA kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the filter applies a specific ROI, we may copy the ROI from host to device, apply filter on the ROI, and copy the filtered ROI from device to host.

For copy a ROI from host to device and back, we may use [cudaMemcpy2D](http://horacio9573.no-ip.org/cuda/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g17f3a55e8c9aef5f90b67cdf22851375.html) instead of `cudaMemcpy`.

---

When using `cudaMemcpy2D`, we have to set the "source pitch" and "destination pitch"

- The source pitch applies stride (step) in bytes between source rows.
- The destination pitch applies stride (step) in bytes between destination rows.

In the following illustration, we may allocate, copy and process only the small rectangle:

```
<- pitch in bytes: 6144 ->
 ------------------------
|                        |
| face.ptr()             |
|    --> --------        |
|       |        | 144   |
|       |        |height |
|       |        |       |
|        --------        |
|        <-2384 ->       |
|     width in bytes     |
|                        |
 -----------------------
```

---

Code sample (without face detection):

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"

#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>

#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


__global__ void myFilterKernel(int* d_face, int width, int height, int faceStep) {
    int x = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    int face_c = faceStep / width; //Channel count, it should be 3

    if (y < height && x < width) {
        //Thread pos
        int face_tid = y * faceStep + (face_c * x);

        //Filter
        for (int i = 0; i < face_c; i++) {
            d_face[face_tid + i] *= 2;
        }
    }
}


void myFilter(Mat face, int w, int h, int THREADS){
    //It's confirmed that w, h = 194
    int img_pitch = (int)face.step[0]; //Source stride in bytes - applies input image row size in bytes (512*3*4 = 6144).
    int roi_pitch = w * (int)face.step[1]; //Destination stride in bytes - applies roi row size in bytes (194*3*4 = 2328).

    /*CUDA WORK*/
    //int faceBytes = face.step[0]*face.rows;  //Should be face.elemSize()*sizeof(int)*w*h = 3*4*194*194, but it gives 3*4*512*194
    int faceBytes = roi_pitch * h; //We may copy only the ROI, and not the entire image.

    int *d_face;
    cudaMalloc<int>(&d_face, faceBytes);

    //cudaMemcpy(d_face, face.ptr(), faceBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    //2D (ROI) copy from host to device.
    cudaMemcpy2D(d_face,                    //void *dst,
                 roi_pitch,                 //size_t dpitch,    //2384 bytes
                 face.ptr(),                //const void *src,  
                 img_pitch,                 //size_t spitch,    //6144 bytes
                 roi_pitch,                 //size_t width, //width in bytes equals roi_pitch //2384 bytes
                 h,                         //size_t height,    //144 rows
                 cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);   //enum cudaMemcpyKind kind);

    dim3 threadsPerBlock(THREADS, THREADS);
    dim3 numBlocks((unsigned int)ceil(w / threadsPerBlock.x), (unsigned int)ceil(h / threadsPerBlock.y));

    //myFilterKernel<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_face, w, h, face.step1());
    myFilterKernel<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_face, w, h, w*3); //Pass step in units of int32 elements.

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    //cudaMemcpy(face.ptr(), d_face, faceBytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    //2D copy from device to host
    cudaMemcpy2D(face.ptr(),                //void *dst,
                 img_pitch,                 //size_t dpitch,    //6144 bytes
                 d_face,                    //const void *src,
                 roi_pitch,                 //size_t spitch,    //2384 bytes
                 roi_pitch,                 //size_t width,     //width in bytes equals roi_pitch //2384 bytes
                 h,                         //size_t height,    //144
                 cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);   //enum cudaMemcpyKind kind);

    cudaFree(d_face);
}


int main()
{
    int THREADS = 8;

    string path = "lenna.png"; //512x512 size
    Mat img = imread(path);

    //The int conversion is needed for my final filter (blur).
    img.convertTo(img, CV_32SC3);

    //Rect R = setROI(faces[i]); //Adjust black rectangle region.
    Rect R = cv::Rect(204, 188, 194, 194);

    Point top_left = R.tl();
    Point bot_right = R.br();

    int w = bot_right.x - top_left.x;
    int h = bot_right.y - top_left.y;

    Mat faceROI = img(R);
    //faceROI.convertTo(faceROI, CV_32SC3); //Image is already converted to CV_32SC3

    //Filter apply
    myFilter(faceROI, w, h, THREADS);

    //Draws rectangles. Green one is for detected face and black one is for previous adjustment.
    rectangle(img, R.tl(), R.br(), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 3);
    //rectangle(img, top_left, bot_right, Scalar(0, 0, 0), 3);

    //Recover original format.
    img.convertTo(img, CV_8UC3);

    imwrite("test.jpg", img);

    //Show output image for testing"):
    imshow("img", img);
    waitKey();
    destroyAllWindows();


    return 0;
}
```

---

Output:
[image]

Note:

- Most filters requires small environment around the pixel.
  In that case, we may have to copy larger ROI from host to device (and copy the exact ROI from device to host).
  In that case, testing if the pixel exceeds the image boundaries may become more complicated.

Comment: Thank you so much! The solution works like a charm. About your note, in fact, the black rectangle area in my problem description is my larger ROI (environment of variable radius) and the green one is the one I want to apply the filter. By now, I'll just check if the thread is inside the green region in the kernel; but it would be great if I get a way to just copy the green region to the kernel from the large black ROI, reducing the unused threads.

Comment: In order to copy a ROI, all we need is the pointer to the top left corner, the ROI width, and the pitch/stride/step in bytes. It doesn't matter if the green region is inside a black region (as long we can calculate the pointer to the top left corner). My comment address the case, when we have to copy the ROI with some margins around it - in that case, there is a problem when the ROI is at the edge of the image.